# Spring Boot mutual authentication failing in handshake

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, resttemplate

I have a `RestTemplate` client embedded in a `SpringBoot` application like below,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SecureAppClientApplication {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecureAppClientApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecureAppClientApplication.class, args);
        LOG.debug("Testing connecting to secure site");
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier ((hostname, session) -> false);
        RestTemplate restTemp = new RestTemplate();
        String greetings = restTemp.getForObject("https://my.secure.service", String.class);
        LOG.debug("Received greetings from secured server ---> " + greetings );
    }
}
```

The `application.proerties` for which reads something like,

```
server.ssl.key-store=myKeyStore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=Store@123
server.ssl.key-alias=myClient
server.ssl.key-password=Key@1234
server.ssl.trust-store=cacerts
server.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
```

There are other properties as well, but unrelated to HTTPS (like Logging, JPA, etc)

Now, with a certificate of the host, exported from browser (Mozilla), I installed the same in

- `myKeyStore.jks` present at classpath,
- copy of `cacerts` present at classpath,
- `cacerts` at JDK home, and
- `cacerts` at JRE home

Still I'm getting PKIX validation error, root of which is

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Not sure how get started with trouble-shooting. Is it the

- Certificate extracted from browser, since I had earlier tested with X509 certificates generated by `openssl`.
- Server root-path; I'm trying to access 'https://host/service' whereas certificate shows information for 'https://host' only
- Import using `keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias my-alias`

**UPDATE**
It seems to be a certificate issue. Turns out, getting a certificate from browser doesn't really help. I contacted my server-host admin, and got 3 certificates to get installed. Silly me relying on browser certificate. I guess there's something like `certificate chaining`.

**CONCLUSION**
Make sure to get appropriate certificates in real use case, because the world just doesn't rely on simple certificates available on browsers, especially for web-service calls.

Comment: It appears that you need to set up trust, but instead you're adding the site's keys to your keystore, unless I am misunderstanding something from your example. Did you attempt to use the keytool to add the sites cert to your trust store?

Comment: I believe `cacerts` file provided with Java installation serves as the `trust-store`. I already mentioned where all the certificate has been installed. Do I need to add anything more ?

Answer (score 0):

For this case it was getting the right certificates, as I was not knowing a lot about them. You may be requiring multiple certificates.